# Input tag does not pick up width below 20px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set the width of an input tag of type button to 16px but it is not taking width below 20px and does not reduce the size.

[image]

I want to have a button with the green check image on it and its size should be below 20px but I am unable to do so using input tag. if I simply take img instead of input tag, then it won't have same press effects like those of a button.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: copy your example code to snippet, so that its easy to solve

Comment: you can use the img tag and add an onclick to the image to achieve the desired effects

Answer (score 2):

It does obey sizes below 20px. You need to override *innate* padding on buttons **Proof:**
[image]

A clear knowledge of what's default for a button is required (ignore the innermost box)

[image]

```css
.tick {
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
}
.tick-20px {
  height:20px;
  width:20px
}
.btn-10px {
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-10px"></button>
<button><img class="tick" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/accept-tick-icon-12.png"></button>
<button><img class="tick-20px" src="http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/accept-tick-icon-12.png"></button>
```

Comment: Actually problem is that button's size won't go below 20px.. It will not take the value. Is there some min width defined for a button or input tag ?? I need the size of the button similar to as shown in my posted image...

Comment: I have used the same way but unable to achieve the desired results...

Comment: Here in your example, it has reduced the size of the image but size of the button is not reduced to 10px

Comment: See my edited answer

Comment: whatever the requirement is, in this era of mobile, i really _really_ think if a button of size 10px is clickable on a mobile even with the smallest of thumbs with other elements floating around :P look at the button there in the pic, rests there like the smallest of the smallest buttons, with a 2px border, effectively giving a 6px usable space inside, in which you may want to fill in that seemingly invisible tick

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation.. I m quite new to HTML, so don't know much about these styles..

Answer (score 0):

try to use same size of image what you want for your button size

```
<input type="button" style="width:16px; height:16px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-image:url(Styles/Images/imgres.png)"/>
```

here my image size is same as button size 16px * 16px

Comment: make it a snippet, so it is viewable by users